# SQL Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

This is my first database assignment so apologise for being a complete novice.
I have just completed my database in Oracle 11g express and have populated it with data.

I am required to make specific query's but my issue is the default format of any output from my database.Here is an example of the output from selecting a table:

```
BUYER_NO             TITLE                FIRST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SURNAME              ADDRESS                                            POSTCODE
-------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------
DESIRED_PROPERTY_TYPE          DES     BUDGET CONTACT_NO   TOWN
------------------------------ --- ---------- ------------ ------------

BY003                Mr                   Callum
Oldfield             4 Root Street                                      BH8 B2K
Detached                       3       425000 01202 889452 Bournmouth

BY004                Mrs                  Jacqueline
Somerset             87 Cleveland Avenue                                BH8 SPT
```

Is there anyway to make the outputs look more presentable for my assignment? thank you.